# Behat - How to implement a step definition that targets all pages?

Tags: php, testing, behat, gherkin, mink

I am trying to test a feature and ensure it shows itself on any page. How can I implement a custom step in my context class for something like

```
Scenario: ...
  Given I am on any page
  Then I should see "..."
  Then ...
```

without using 100 separate lined calls to `MinkContext::visit` for the 100 different parts of the site (example.com/a/, example.com/b/, example.com/a/a/ ...)?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom step like:

```
/**
 * @Given /^I am on (.*) page$/
 */
public function iAmOnPage($page)
{
    // call method to navigate to page identified by key
}
```

the `$page` param could be a key that identifies the page or a relative path to the  base_url, depends on you on how you organize the code.